# tryCatch print the expression in the handler

Tags: r

Basically, try something as follows:

```
tryCatch(expr = {stop("stop message")},
         error = function(e) {
           cat(conditionMessage(e))
           cat(as.character(expr))
         })
```

with expect output to be something like: `"stop(\"stop message\")"`, but fails as `expr` cannot be found... Any way to print `expr` within the scope without having to do something as follows?

```
expr <- eval('stop("stop message")')
tryCatch(expr = {expr},
         error = function(e) {
           cat(conditionMessage(e))
           cat(as.character(expr))
         })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd really recommend this, but you could walk up the call stack to find the `tryCatch` call and extract the parameter there. Here's a helper function to find a call in the call stack

```
findStackFun <- function(fun) {
  for(cx in sys.calls()) {
    if (deparse(cx[[1]]) == fun) {
      return(cx)
    }
  }
  return(NULL)
}
```

Then you could run

```
tryCatch(expr = {stop("stop message")},
         error = function(e) {
           cat(conditionMessage(e))
           call <- findStackFun("tryCatch")
           cat(deparse(call$expr))
         })
```